Match end of file name in .gitignore
In a git repo, I want to exclude a file named main but not a file named main.c. How would I do this?
If I add this to the .gitignore file:
main

both files are excluded. How do I match a pattern at the end of a file name in a .gitignore?
I found out I could just add !main.* to the gitignore, but is there a cleaner way to achieve the same result, perhaps with something like main^?

If it's a single file you would like to avoid ignoring, just leave the line as you have it there and run git add -f main.c. It would need to be done once and then the file is tracked and .gitignore won't affect it

Actually, it's more like multiple files, and multiple users may want to access them and edit their changes. Would what you suggest not make it easier to think you added a file and not actually commit the changes?

Ah, no.... I think you are mistaken in terms of what .gitignore does. It only affects files that are not tracked. Once a file is tracked, .gitignore does not affect it.... so, once you force git to track it (even if a line in .gitignore says it should be ignored), git will report when the file is changed from that moment on, regardless of what .gitignore has.

And what I am saying is that you add the file (or files) and you commit it so all developers get it... and they can continue working on it as if .gitignore did not have a rule to ignore it... because it is already tracked, it does not matter what .gitignore says.

Anyway... that works if it's only a couple of files, say.... also if the files that you would like to avoid from ignoring do not change over time... if you have a line in .gitignore that will keep on nagging you for new files that are added over time, then the trick is not good enough.

@eftshift0 Thanks for the explanation on how .gitignore files work, I indeed got it wrong; however what you are suggesting doesn't really answer my question as just adding !main.* looks nicer to me compared to forcing adding files.

As it turns out, the issue I was encountering had something to do with the fact that main.c was in a folder named main, which was ignored beforehand... Adding !/ to the .gitignore solves the problem and the question doesn't make sense anymore: .gitignores do know how to match the end of a file name, I just used them wrong.

I get
$ cd `mktemp -d`; git init
[…]
$ echo main >.gitignore
$ >main; >main.c
$ git add -n .
add '.gitignore'
add 'main.c'
$

so I don't know what else you're doing to get

both files are excluded

but whatever's happening I think I did exactly as you describe and didn't get those results.
Maybe main is a directory? Directory exclusions summarily exclude the entire contents regardless of name, that's the point: to tell git not to even look there for new files to track. If that's the case, you can say !main/ to stop directories named main being dropped whole like that.
Anyway, try doing git ls-files -oc | git check-ignore --stdin -v to see exactly why all excluded files are excluded, and add the -n flag to the checkignore to see all the files that aren't ignored too, showing any explicit no-exclude rules that stopped earlier ones matching.

Indeed, main is in a directory named "main"... that explains things

add to .gitignore:
# Ignore all files containing "main" in their filename
*main*

# But do not ignore main.c
!main.c

